# Django send mail and sms after 6 hours of user sign up

Tags: python, django, email

I am using django 1.9. I am working on requirement where we need to send users reminder to activate their account by email after x hours h/she has signed on our platform.

I have send_mail task and I have configured [Django RQ](https://github.com/ui/django-rq) to send mails.

One way I can think of is to set up a cron job using [Django RQ scheduler](https://github.com/ui/rq-scheduler) which runs every 5 mins to check for users who signed up 6 hours before.

Is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: i recommend http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html.

Comment: Thanks but I have already django rq and rq scheduler configured and running properly so I was avoiding adding one more task manager such as celery.

Comment: ok. so you can schedule task after x hours na?You will get trigger using  model signals https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/. Then no need of cronjob for this purpose.

Comment: Ok thanks, But  how I can trigger post_save signal after x hour ? It gets invoked as soon as model save is performed na

Comment: yup.when you got trigger, put x hours schedule time like, `job = scheduler.enqueue_at(datetime(X hour from current time), func)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the django-rq documentation, if you have both `django-rq` and `rq-scheduler` installed, it seems you don't need to create a periodic job. Just schedule your job during sign on.

```
# From django-rq docs 
import django_rq
# Select the queue you want to use, here it uses default queue
scheduler = django_rq.get_scheduler('default')
# HERE: Set the datetime X HOURS from sign on 
job = scheduler.enqueue_at(datetime(2020, 10, 10), func)
```

Reference: [django-rq docs Support for RQ Scheduler](https://github.com/ui/django-rq) section

Note: I haven't used Django-RQ myself.